# Can not find jdk.dio package

Tags: java

I use openjdk18. When I am importing jdk.dio.mmio, the IDE says cannot find jdk.dio package. I also find the jdk package only has few packages. This pages says jdk.* is existed.
https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/dio-jmee8/api/jdk/dio/mmio/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

The `jdk.dio.mmio` package is a Java ME package. It is not part of Java SE ... which is what OpenJDK Java 18 is.

There is nothing that is directly equivalent to the Java ME `jdk.dio.mmio` package in Java SE.

---

A DIO (device I/O) codebase is available in the java.net Mercurial repositories; see https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/dio/Getting+Started for more information.

- It doesn't look like the source code on java.net corresponds to the Java ME javadocs that you found.
- I suspect that the Java ME version of the source code is only available to Java ME (source) license holders.  AFAIK, it is not open source.